# How Do I Authenticate a User With Shiro?

Tags: shiro

I've gone over and over on how to have a user login with Shiro, but it still seems like a vital piece is missing: How does shiro authenticate a given username and password against stored usernames and passwords? The most I've figured out is `It is each Realm's responsibility to match submitted credentials with those stored in the Realm's backing data store` [from here](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-authentication). But how is that done?

Below is what I've tried, but the result is still an invalid authentication.

LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object cmd, BindException errors) throws Exception {

    LoginCommand command = (LoginCommand) cmd;
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(command.getUsername(), command.getPassword());
    System.out.println("onSubmit");
    System.out.println(token.getUsername());
    System.out.println(token.getPassword());

    try
    {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        errors.reject("error.invalidLogin", "The username or password was not correct.");
    }

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return showForm(request, response, errors);
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("accessTest");
    }
}
```

Realm

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authcToken) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = (UsernamePasswordToken) authcToken;

    System.out.println("doGetAuthenticationInfo");
    System.out.println(user.getUsername());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());

    // user is a test object in place of a database
    if( user != null ) {
        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getName());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share output?  My first guess is that token.getPassword() != user.getPassword().

Comment: It is. I've tested all output, all output is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the answer. It was a foolish one. I copied some example code, and they set the credentials matcher to HashedCredentialsMatcher. I wasn't doing any hashing, so it didn't work. Removed the setCredentialsMatcher and it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you so long later. Could you post the full class of your  realm. I cannot find any examples explaining what the class name should be so I can authenticate users in my db :(

Comment: Sorry @chrisloughnane, that code is long gone, so I'm afraid I can't help you.